# Connecting to multiple mongodb instances from django

Tags: django, mongodb, mongoengine

I am using mongoengine with Django and within my project need to connect to two instances of MongoDB while serving single request. It works just fine if I use:

```
connect("mdb1")
#do stuff with mdb1
...
connect("mdb2")
#do stuff with mdb2
```

but I am wondering if that's a proper way of doing it.

Comment: What is the problem with that? What is the question? How else do you want to connect to any database without explictly opening explict database connections at *some* point?

Answer (score 12):

[Multiple database](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases) support was added in MongoEngine 0.6

Demo using [`register_connection`](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.register_connection).

```
alias_lists = ['users-books-db', 'user-db', 'book-db'] # list of aliases
dbs = ['author-book-pairs', 'users', 'books'] # list of databases
for alias, db in zip(alias_lists, dbs):
    register_connection(alias, db)

class User(Document):
    name = StringField()
    meta = {"db_alias": "user-db"}

class Book(Document):
    name = StringField()
    meta = {"db_alias": "book-db"}

class AuthorBooks(Document):
    author = ReferenceField(User)
    book = ReferenceField(Book)
    meta = {"db_alias": "users-books-db"}
```

Comment: One thing though... this does not work with DynamicDocuments, esp. when the meta needs to be added dynamically at runtime

Answer (score 2):

@Ricardo at the official documentation theres a section explaining context management (i.e switching databases using the same document: http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#switch-database).
The following code will switch the class `User`, originally stored in  `users-db` to the new database `archive-user-db`

```
from mongoengine.context_managers import switch_db

class User(Document):
     name = StringField()

     meta = {"db_alias": "user-db"}

with switch_db(User, 'archive-user-db') as User:
     User(name="Ross").save()  # Saves the 'archive-user-db'
```

Comment: The pertinent information should also be included in addition to the source URL

Comment: The link has been broken. http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#switch-database

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no a proper way to do this. The example of Matt turns obligatory use an connection by Document type. If I want to use one document with many connections the example doesn't fit.