# MongoEngine change database

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongoengine

Due to my project setup (same as [flasky](http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky)) , when I run my python tests ([line 34](http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/manage.py)), a connection to the development database is created, before my configuration is set to test (line 11 [here](http://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/tests/test_api.py)). This results in problems with my tests, since they are meant to run on a clean DB.

Looking online, I only found descriptions of [switch_db](http://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/apireference.html?highlight=switch_db#mongoengine.context_managers.switch_db) but this is not what I need. I need to either change the database my connection is using, or drop the connection and create a new one. I cant find a way to do either of these.. Am I missing something ? My connection is simply initialized using this line of code, inside **init**.py of my main app directory.

```
from mongoengine import connection
db_name = 'name_from_config'
connection(db_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this in mongoengine

```
from flask.ext.mongoengine import mongoengine
mongoengine.register_connection("alias1", "db1")
mongoengine.register_connection("alias2", "db2")
```

and in model, add in entry in meta or use switch method of queryset

[similar question at stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6067645/connecting-to-multiple-mongodb-instances-from-django)

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid creating the connection to mongoengine in the way you describe for precisely this reason. Flasky is using an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) approach which allows the application  to know which connection config to use when implementing the data models.

The best way to integrate mongoenigne into your app is with something like [flask-mongoengine](https://flask-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which will should solve this problem out-of-the-box.

Comment: Not sure how mongoengine plugin would solve this problem. What I have done to go around it is provide a system param for config, which means I use the right one from start.

Comment: environment variable *

Comment: Well if it works it works ;-) The plugin is useful because it provides a few extra features as well as making mongodb work in application factories with little code.